# Is it possible to create sxa page in non sxa website?

Tags: sxa, migration

We have recently migrated 4 websites from sitecore 7.2 to sitecore 9.1. we have not done any major code changes and websites are still running in asp.net webforms. We have upgraded the license to include SXA. We are in need of creating a page completely using SXA in non-SXA(existing migrated websites) website. Is that possible? If yes, How do you suggest implementing SXA in the existing webforms website?

We would like to give a try to have one SXA page in non SXA website.

Comment: Do you have installed SXA in this instance?

Comment: yes i have installed sxa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - this is not possible. An SXA Page requires the SXA layout and the predefined structure for an SXA site. Either the site must be *all* SXA or it is just not SXA. The *only* way to convert your existing web-forms site into SXA is a complete re-write.

You *can* have SXA and non SXA sites in the same instance, that will work fine. But you can't mix the page items like that.

You can also mix webforms & MVC in the same site, the MVC pages will need their own layout and *all* components on the page must be MVC, but it is one way to migrate a site to MVC without re-writing the entire site at once.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will be able to do that.

Firstly, the views (.cshmlt) used by SXA won't be reachable by your pages if they are not part of an SXA website. You are going to have a lot of these:

[image]

Secondly, you said your old pages are **webform based**. SXA is MVC only, so again you will need to rework this part of your instance if you want to use the accelerator here.